# html jquery Sort strings of different sizes

Tags: jquery, html

is it possible?
i want this:
[image]

```
 <div>
  <a style="font-size:30px">#abc</a>
  <a style="font-size:60px">#abc</a>
  <a style="font-size:30px">#abc</a>
  <a style="font-size:30px">#abc</a>
  <a style="font-size:30px">#abc</a>
  <a style="font-size:30px">#abc</a>
  <a style="font-size:30px">#abc</a>
  <a style="font-size:60px">#abc</a>
  <a style="font-size:30px">#abc</a>
  <a style="font-size:30px">#abc</a>
  <a style="font-size:30px">#abc</a>
  <a style="font-size:30px">#abc</a>
  <a style="font-size:30px">#abc</a>
  <a style="font-size:30px">#abc</a>
  <a style="font-size:30px">#abc</a></div>
```

i try using float tag but It was not the answer I wanted.

Comment: Look at [Mosaic](https://jquery-mosaic.tin.cat/) or similar.,

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible? Kinda..
Flexbox offers a solution to what you may want to do.

```css
div{
  width: 50%;
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}
div > a{
  flex-grow: 1;

}
```

```html
  <div>
   <a style="font-size:20px">#abc</a>
   <a style="font-size:60px">#abc</a>
   <a style="font-size:10px">#abc</a>
   <a style="font-size:30px">#abc</a>
   <a style="font-size:60px">#abc</a>
   <a style="font-size:10px">#abc</a>
   <a style="font-size:15px">#abc</a>
   <a style="font-size:60px">#abc</a>
   <a style="font-size:18px">#abc</a>
   <a style="font-size:15px">#abc</a>
   <a style="font-size:60px">#abc</a>
   <a style="font-size:18px">#abc</a>
   <a style="font-size:30px">#abc</a>
   <a style="font-size:30px">#abc</a>
   <a style="font-size:30px">#abc</a>
   <a style="font-size:60px">#abc</a>
   <a style="font-size:10px">#abc</a>
 </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But the answer I want is to fill in the blank spaces with words